# Create list alert using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, alert

I want to create a list alert using the rest endpoint `_api/web/alerts/add`. For this I build a JSON-string representing an `AlertCreationInformation`-object.

I tested this `AlertCreationInformation`-object using CSOM `Web.Alerts.Add()` and it works perfectly. But when POSTing this to  `_api/web/alerts/add` things break.

Headers:

```
{
  "Accept ": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
```

Payload:

```
{
  "AlertFrequency": 2,
  "AlertTemplateName": "SPAlertTemplateType.WebPageLibrary",
  "AlertType": 2,
  "AlwaysNotify": "true",
  "DeliveryChannels": 1,
  "EventType": 1,
  "Filter": "<Query><And><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"SomeField\"/><Value type=\"string\">Word</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"SomeField\"/><Value type=\"string\">Excel</Value></Eq></Or><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"SomeSkill\"/><Value type=\"string\">2 - Fortgeschritten</Value></Eq></Or></And></Query>",
  "List": "3b80d325-4031-4de5-ae7f-5f6dd5f86b72",
  "Title": "My Filtered Notification",
  "User": 6
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The parameter \"AlertFrequency\" does not exist in the method \"Add\".\r\nclientRequestId: 77c80643-3a85-4c9e-8692-a3e19dafa988\r\nserviceRequestId: 02d5e69e-607c-8000-893a-517bd9aa37e8",
  "source": "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/_api/web/alerts/add",
  "errors": [
    "-1",
    "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException"
  ]
}
```

The error-message always cites the first parameter in the JSON-object when I change the order. I also tried adding the property `"__metadata": { "type": "SP.AlertCreationInformation" }` or wrapping the AlertCreationInformation object inside `{ "parameters": {  .. object here ... }`. Still the same error, just referencing the properties `__metadata` or `parameters`.

How do I get this working?

Comment: Were you able to create list alert by this method? I am also trying this approach and I also have same queries as you had.
Please let me know if there is any solution on this.

Comment: AFAIR it did not work over Rest  (see Bad Gateway comment below) and we switched to An Azure Function using CSOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data like this:

```
{
    "alertCreationInformation":{    
        "__metadata":{"type": "SP.AlertCreationInformation"},
        ...
    }
}
```

And the [SP.AlertCreationInformation](https://s-kainet.github.io/sp-rest-explorer/#/entity/SP.AlertCreationInformation) properties as below.

```
Property             Type
AlertFrequency       Int32
AlertTemplateName    String
AlertTime            DateTime
AlertType            Int32
AlwaysNotify         Boolean
DeliveryChannels     Int32
EventType            Int32
EventTypeBitmask     Int32
Filter               String
Properties           Collection (SP.KeyValue)
Status               Int32
Title                String
```

Refer to: [SharePoint REST API Metadata Explorer](https://s-kainet.github.io/sp-rest-explorer/#/_api/web/Alerts/Add)

Comment: This is looking good, but unlike the CSOM Version I cannot reference a list. Where do I put this parameter?

Comment: Fetching the existing alerts by _api/web/alerts also does not point the alerts to any list... Or do I just point to the ViewID... will try this.

Comment: You can access /_api/$metadata to see the REST API metadata.

Comment: Your answer worked so far, that I can POST the request to the endpoint and I get no more errors concerning bad parameters or the like, but now I get "502 Bad Gateway" without any more helpful details. But as you answered the initial question, the bounty is yours.

Comment: Oh, I have to wait 8 hours before award the bounty to you SO said.

Comment: Hi @ben If possible, could you please your rest code here. I am trying to implement the same thing(create alert using REST API) but I am not able to do it.