# Is there a client API to manage user's alerts for document libraries/files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, alert, microsoft-graph

In SharePoint users can use the "Alert me" function to get notified of file changes in a document library (or single files):

[image]

Is there a client API to set those alerts? E.g. from a SharePoint Framework web part?

We'd like to provide a more streamlined UI for a user to manage their alerts. We'd need access  (create/read/update) to the user's alerts to do this. Can this be done?

(SharePoint API is fine, Graph API is fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read alerts from SharePoint site using:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/alerts
```

You can read alerts from SharePoint site using:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/alerts/add
```

For more information, check this thread: [Create list alert using REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262556/create-list-alert-using-rest)